# .vimrc file not working as expected

Tags: python, ubuntu, vim

If I open a python file with vim, and set it to have a ruler and auto-line break with this command:

```
:set textwidth=109 colorcolumn=110
```

It works like a charm! However ... if I edit `~/.vimrc` and add this line at the bottom

```
autocmd FileType py set textwidth=109 colorcolumn=110
```

exit the python file, and open it again, nothing happens. Seems like something is overriding my setting, but can't figure out what is doing that (because I'm fairly new to vim). My basic vimrc file is this: https://github.com/amix/vimrc/blob/master/vimrcs/basic.vim

Can someone point me in the right direction on what am I doing wrong?

Note: the same thing is happening for Javascript files when I try to "replace" Tabs with 2 spaces in indentation:

```
autocmd FileType js setlocal sw=2 sts=2 et
```

Comment: I would recommend putting the settings and mappings into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/{filetype}.vim` instead of defining lots of `:autocmd FileType {filetype}`; this requires that you have `:filetype plugin on`.

Comment: I'll look into that. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that the correct filetypes are `python` and `javascript` (or similar, like `javascript.jsx` if you have additional syntax files), not `py` and `js`. You can check the filetype used for a file by `:set ft?`.

Also, you may prefer `setlocal` (to affect only the current buffer) instead of `set`.